# To accept response of type ZIP from API using angular 7?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, zip

Im trying to download a zip file to my local system by using API response to be of type zip using angular.but since it's of type zip i'm not able to accept that rather running into error.

a.service.ts

```
 download() {
        const headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
            "content-type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/zip"
        });
        return this.http.get(url, {headers: headers, responseType: "arraybuffer"});
    }
```

a.component.ts

```
getDownload() {
        console.log("Hello world");
        this.Service.download().subscribe((responseData: any) => {
        console.log(responseData);
        },(error: any) => {
        });
```

error:
[image]

Tried by adding responseType to be "blob","text" and "arraybuffer"...nothing seems to be working

[image]

Comment: Try using `blob` instead of `arraybuffer`, and remove your headers

Comment: Can you also show a screenshot of the request headers, from the network tab?

Comment: @David yes added

Comment: Is that after removing the headers?

Comment: @David No,before that...building image to check after removing headers will update

Comment: Can't you just test in dev instead of doing a build? If this still does not work, maybe you have an interceptor somewhere that changes responseType?

Comment: @David Have a problem with API access has to work an particular dev instance and rebuild image each time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213858/discussion-between-new123-and-david).

Comment: works...after removing headers and replacing with blob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the headers from your request and set responseType to `blob`

If you specify these headers, this will overwrite the default parsing from the `blob` response type and try to parse the zip file as json data